# Validate arguments and set value if empty with bash function

Tags: bash, function, validation, arguments

I have a function that enables me to check for unset variables:

```
ValidateArgs () {
for Var in "$@" ; do
    echo "Validating argument $Var with value \"${!Var}\"."
    if [ -z "${!Var}" ] ; then
        echo "Argument \"$Var\" is required. Please define $Var."
        read -rp "Enter $Var: " Var
        echo -e "\n"
    fi
done
}
```

I'd like to enhance this function so it is able to set a value for the arguments passed after reading it with `read -rp`.

I tried several combinations, is it possible to do this and if so what would be the ebst way?

The function is called like this:

```
ValidateArgs Action HostName
```

if Action and HostName are unset after going through the ValidateArgs function a value is asked and should be set. I would prefer to use the function in the main script.

Comment: Technically, you aren't checking for unset variables; you are checking for variables that lack a non-empty value. Read up on the `-v` operator and `${var:?msg}` parameter expansions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a script and run it inside the original shell using `source` like this:

```
ValidateArgs () {
for Var in "$@" ; do
    echo "Validating argument $Var with value \"${!Var}\"."
    if [ -z "${!Var}" ] ; then
        echo "Argument \"$Var\" is required. Please define $Var."
        printf "Enter $Var: "
        read value
        export $Var=$value
    fi
done
}

ValidateArgs $@
```

One you do this, you can run the script like:

```
source ./test.sh myvar
Validating argument myvar with value "".
Argument "myvar" is required. Please define myvar.
Enter myvar: myvalue

echo $myvar
myvalue
```

Comment: I would prefer to use the function in the main script if possible, to avoid dependencies. But interesting suggestion, tx.

Comment: I was able to use the export method in the main script. Answer accepted. Cheers